# JSON flattening in athena (converting all keys into columns)

Tags: sql, arrays, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have data like below. And I want all keys to convert as columns (table structure consists of columns as same as json keys). I want all values to be reflected in rows.

```
WITH dataset AS (
   SELECT '{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John Doe",
      "age": 30,
      "address": {
         "street": "123 Main St",
         "city": "Anytown",
         "state": "CA",
         "zipcode": "12345"
      },
      "contacts": [
         {
            "type": "email",
            "value": "john.doe@example.com"
         },
         {
            "type": "phone",
            "value": "555-1234"
         }
      ],
      "orders": [
         {
            "orderId": "A123",
            "products": [
               {
                  "productId": "P001",
                  "name": "Product 1",
                  "quantity": 2
               },
               {
                  "productId": "P002",
                  "name": "Product 2",
                  "quantity": 1
               }
            ],
            "totalAmount": 150.99
         },
         {
            "orderId": "B456",
            "products": [
               {
                  "productId": "P003",
                  "name": "Product 3",
                  "quantity": 3
               }
            ],
            "totalAmount": 75.50
         }
      ]
   }' AS myblob
)
```

I'm expecting a result something like this:

```
+----+----------+-----+--------------+---------+-------+---------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+------------+---------------+----------+-------------+
| id | name     | age | street       | city    | state | zipcode | contact_type  | contact_value       | order_id  | product_id    | product_name | quantity      | totalAmount  |
+----+----------+-----+--------------+---------+-------+---------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+------------+---------------+--------------+
| 1  | John Doe | 30  | 123 Main St  | Anytown | CA    | 12345   | email         | john.doe@example.com | A123      | P001         | Product 1   | 2             | 150.99       |
| 1  | John Doe | 30  | 123 Main St  | Anytown | CA    | 12345   | email         | john.doe@example.com | A123      | P002         | Product 2   | 1             | 150.99       |
| 1  | John Doe | 30  | 123 Main St  | Anytown | CA    | 12345   | phone         | 555-1234            | B456      | P003         | Product 3   | 3             | 75.50        |
+----+----------+-----+--------------+---------+-------+---------+---------------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+------------+---------------+--------------+
```

I'm trying it with the `UNNEST` function, but I'm not able to get the result as expected.

Comment: Please show your attempt. Also it is not clear what is the rule for matching contacts and orders. Do you want to match them by id in the array (then why do you have 3 rows in the result) or do you want to have a Cartesian product of addresses and arrays?

Comment: I'm trying with below approach.        SELECT
   id,
   name,
   age,
   contact.type AS contact_type,
   contact.value AS contact_value,
   order.orderId AS order_id,
   product.product_id,
   product.name AS product_name,
   product.quantity,
   order.totalAmount
FROM dataset,
   UNNEST(contacts) AS contact
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(orders) AS order ON TRUE
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(order.products) AS product ON TRUE;

Comment: 1) Add it to the question please. 2) Please  add results of this query 3) Also please answer second part of the question - how contact and product should be matched